# XA with dockerized Websphere MQ

Tags: ibm-mq

If XA is used as a XA Transaction Manager using Java MQ classes, not JTA, the Java application and the WMQ, both need to reside on the same host machine. I have been told this is because shared memory is used as Inter Process Communication mechanism.

If we use deploy WMQ in a docker container and keep our Java application in another docker container, both on the same host, will we be able to use the WMQ as a XA coordinator?

Will we have to use certain special configuration of the container to get it working?

Regards,
Yash